# Googlemaps api V3 error loading the api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to use google maps api on my site. I am adding the following url as my script source http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD4RDCq5jqjyooPAQM3MDPTWFR1LDq1N6s&sensor=true. And when I load the page I get the following error.[image: Error generated on my site]

I checked my google aps console and the google api is turned on
[image: Image from google api console]

I am not sure why I am getting this error. My website url is sporkstick.com.
[image: My other google api settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a link to a live demo? Without that, I can only guess that the referrer (i.e. the site that you're putting a map on) does not match the restrictions on referrers you've set up in the API console.

-

You're using the V2 API. Definitely start by loading the V3 Maps API. The V2 API is deprecated. If you look at your console, you've only activated the V3 API for that key, not the V2 API.

Comment: the livedemo is on sporkstick.com. And I am just using the api to get the coordinates for a particular location.

Comment: You're using the V2 API. Definitely start by loading the V3 Maps API. The V2 API is deprecated. If you look at your console, you've only activated the V3 API for that key, not the V2 API.

Comment: You were right they renamed all the functions in V3. That was the reason my code was not responding properly

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
```

keys are not necessary in v3

Comment: That stoped giving me the error but its not working. i have some code that use to work with V2. Now they are not working.

Comment: Do you have a link to live code?  Sounds like you're trying to load the Maps API V3 library and using V2 code. They are not compatible.

Comment: @user899893 there are some differences between the v3 api and the v2 api. If you choose to use v3 you should check out the online documentation and make the necessary changes